# Explain why TypeError is thrown in this Ruby script

Tags: ruby

In this script:

```
dictionary = [
  "below","down","go","going","horn","how","howdy","it","i","low","own","part",
  "partner","sit"
]

def substrings(string, dictionary)
  frequencies = Hash.new(0)
  dictionary.each_index do |substring|
    frequencies.store(dictionary.fetch(substring), string.scan(/#{dictionary[substring]}/i).length)
  end
  frequencies.each_pair {|word, count| puts "#{word} => #{count}"}
end

substrings("Howdy partner, sit down! How's it going?", dictionary)
```

if I change `dictionary.each_index` to `dictionary.each`, I get the following error:

```
in `fetch': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)"
```

Please explain why. I understand that `each` returns the values of the array and that `each_index` returns the index.  I cannot get the code to work using `each` and want to understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array#each_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index) iterates through each of the array. This means that for your `dictionary` array, the `substring` variable will be set to `0`, then `1`, then `2`, etc. Each of these values is an Integer.

[Array#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-fetch) expects an Integer as it's argument and returns the value at that index in the array. When you use `each`, you are passing the actual string value instead of the index. Thus, the error you see.

If you want to use [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each), you will need to update your `each` block like this.

```ruby
dictionary.each do |substring|
  frequencies.store(substring, string.scan(/#{substring}/i).length)
end
```

Comment: It is better to do `string.downcase` outside the `each` block, and do `string.scan(substring)`.

Comment: @sawa sure, for performance that would be good. However, I preferred to change the code as little as possible for my answer

Comment: The issue I've been having is if I try to modify the code as you suggest, it throws a "`[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)".  That's why I used the inelegant fetch method in the first place to iterate through the words.

Comment: This code works for me. Here's a sample of the complete code (including my suggested use of `#each`). https://gist.github.com/danielma/76f5515197f180a97f7a

Answer (score 2):

`dictionary` is an array.  `Array#fetch` expects a numerical index and will fetch the value at that index.  If you use `dictionary.each` then `substring` is going to be a string (ie. below, down, go, going, horn, etc.) which isn't a valid argument to the method.

`each_index` works because then `substring` is an integer (the index into the array).